# removing blank lines from text file output python 3

Tags: python, text, edit

I wrote a program in python 3 that edits a text file, and outputs the edited version to a new text file. But the new file has blank lines that I can't have, and I can't figure out how to get rid of them.

Thanks in advance.

```
newData = ""
i=0
run=1
j=0
k=1
seqFile = open('temp100.txt', 'r')
seqData = seqFile.readlines()

while i < 26:
sLine = seqData[j] 
editLine = seqData[k]
tempLine = editLine[0:20]
newLine = editLine.replace(editLine, tempLine)
newData = newData+sLine+'\n'+newLine+'\n'
i=i+1
j=j+2
k=k+2
run=run+1

seqFile.close()

new100 = open("new100a.fastq", "w")
sys.stdout = new100
print(newData)
```

Comment: Much of this code doesn't seem to do anything useful. For example, `editLine.replace(editLine, tempLine)` can't possibly give you anything but `tempLine`. Were you trying to do something different there? Also, why are you redirecting `stdout` just to write to a file, instead of calling `new100.write`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Problem is at this line:

```
newData = newData+sLine+'\n'+newLine+'\n'
```

`sLine` already contains newline symbol, so you should remove the first '\n'. If length of `newLine` is less than 20, then `newLine` also contains the newline. In other case you should add the newline symbol to it.

Try this:

```
newData = newData + sLine + newLine
if len(seqData[k]) > 20:
   newData += '\n'
```

Comment: Perfect! This worked exactly how I needed it to. Thank you immensely.

Answer (score 1):

`sLine` already contains newlines. `newLine` will also contain a newline if `editLine` is shorter or equal to 20 characters long. You can change

`newData = newData+sLine+'\n'+newLine+'\n'`

to

`newData = newData+sLine+newLine`

In cases where `editLine` is longer than 20 characters, the trailing newline will be cut off when you do `tempLine = editLine[0:20]` and you will need to append a newline to `newData` yourself.

According to the python [documentation on readline](http://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#file.readline) (which is used by readlines), trailing newlines are kept in each line:

> Read one entire line from the file. A trailing newline character is
>   kept in the string (but may be absent when a file ends with an
>   incomplete line). [6] If the size argument is present and
>   non-negative, it is a maximum byte count (including the trailing
>   newline) and an incomplete line may be returned. When size is not 0,
>   an empty string is returned only when EOF is encountered immediately.

In general, you can often get a long way in debugging a program by printing the values of your variables when you get unexpected behaviour. For instance printing `sLine` with `print repr(sLine)` would have shown you that there was a trailing newline in there.

Comment: There's no need to guess, and trying to debug code by changing things based on an unconfirmed guess is not a good way for a novice to learn what he's doing. Point to [the docs](http://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#file.readlines), which clearly say that trailing newlines are kept in the string, or explain how to check it (e.g., `print(repr(seqData[0]))`), instead of suggesting that he change it without ever knowing what he's dealing with.

Comment: I should have been more thorough in my answer. I have updated it now.

Comment: Nice answer. It might be a little simpler to just `rstrip` each line and unconditionally add the `\n` instead of trying to figure out whether the newline got cut off by the slice or not… but you've explained enough that the OP should be able to solve the problem however he wants.